# Anti Aliasing making strange gap in skewed navigation

Tags: html, css

I've problem with creating a skewed navigation, actually everything is good except the strange gap between navigation item links. I did bit of research and I saw that is because of Anti Aliasing technique.

I tried to hack it with ::before selector and/or with applying border-right attribute to the block, but no success.

There is code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #1d1e22;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 5%;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #444857;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

ul li a span {
  transform: skew(20deg);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>About us</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>  
</header>
```

I want it to be without the black gap, just in one tone. If you know how to fix it, I will appreciate if you share it.

Comment: A very quick and dirty hack would be to simply place an element with the same background colour behind the menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is how browsers handle **subpixel rendering**. As you are transforming the shape, the browser applies some antialiasing on the edges of the shapes for a smoother rendering.

Because of this there is no guarantee that the edge of two elements will align perfectly. See an [interesting article about it](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/antialiasing-101/).

The quickest fix is to apply some negative margin so that the shapes overlap.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #1d1e22;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 5%;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #444857;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

ul li a span {
  transform: skew(20deg);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>About us</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>  
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

I added a `box-shadow: 1px 0 1px #444857` to the `<a>` tags; https://codepen.io/nosnetrom/pen/QPaMBQ

Comment: Link only answers is not good enough. An answer should contain the code within, or else, when that linked resource dies, so does the value of the this answer.

Comment: I'm using Mozilla Quantum and there is absolutely no effect.